# How do I get the height of an element AFTER dom manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm new to jquery and am having a bit of a tough time figuring this out.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9536959

the margin-top is being set to the height before I manipulate the element. How can I set it up so it gets it after the manipulation?

**edit** I found out that if I separate the functions then it works. can someone explain why this is? is it because the final manipulated element values are not updated until the function finishes?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9537676

Comment: You can try doing this on `setTimeout`, say on half-a-second delay.

Comment: just tried and it doesn't seem to be working =\